# How do I provide the "Find Window's Process" feature in Process Explorer (sysinternals)

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-process

I'm developing an application for debugging purposes. I want the user to be able to select the process to be debugged using the mouse. Process Explorer does a great job of this with the "Find Window's Process" feature. What I can't figure out is how it does this? Does anyone know the Window's API that provides this functionality?

Thanks, Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but it should work: Use `WindowFromPoint` to get the window handle, then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the ID of the process that created the window.

Alternatively, you could use `EnumWindows` to enumerate all top-level windows on the screen, filter them by some criteria (e.g. position) and then use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the process IDs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking to enumerate all Windows and perform some action when the target Window in question is found.  You can do this by enumerating all current [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(v=VS.85).aspx) and then performing some action when the user is over the window in question.  You will have to associate that window handle with a [process](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/0e63cc54-1d6d-44eb-a02c-8cb462eef7dd).

This is not a simple task as it requires going through a lot of hoops but it is possible, just have to put all the pieces together.